# How do I open IDLE 3.4 when 2.7 is already installed?

Tags: python3, idle

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed Python 3.4, but when I enter IDLE in the command line it opens IDLE 2.7, not 3.4. How do I open IDLE 3.4?

Answer (score 2):

Type `sudo apt-get install idle3` to install Idle 3.

Afterwards it can be started with the command `idle3`.